# Problem with flex items and horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I encountered a very strange behaviour with flex items and horizontal scrolling.

If you run the code snippet and scroll to the right, the red border ist not rendered anymore. Also hovering over `.myrow` in dev tools displays only the *visible* part of the row before scrolling.

Can anyone explain this weird behaviour?  (I used chrome)

```css
.mycontainer {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .myrow {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .mycell {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 48px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    background: transparent;
    background-color: #f8f9fb;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer">

  <div class="myrow">
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo</div>
    <div class="mycell">Hallo last</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because of in `.mycontainer` class  you use `flex-direction: column`  remove it and see the change

Comment: ok thx! but I need column here. Look at this pen and scroll to the right. border and background color ignored. Can you explain why this is the case? https://codepen.io/mwager/pen/gEKNMN

Comment: you can use flex direction column in parent that can prevent its child to expand (in row direction) full width in scroll view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *issue* is because the content inside which you've given `overflow-x: auto` are *block elements* - only inline elements *extend to the actual scrollable area*. So `inline-flex` as the *column flexbox* works.

---

**Using a wrapper and inline-flex**

You would need one more wrapper here (say `col` element) which is your *column flexbox* and `mycontainer` only has `oveflow-x` property here - see demo below:

```css
.mycontainer {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.col {
  display: inline-flex; /* an inline display is used here */
  flex-direction: column;
}
.myrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #e7eff5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.mycell {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 48px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: #f8f9fb;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="myrow">
      <div class="mycell">Row1</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo last</div>
    </div>

    <div class="myrow">
      <div class="mycell">Row1</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo last</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Using a wrapper and max-content width**

You can make this work without using `inline-flex` but adding `width: max-content` on the new `col` wrapper around `myrow` - see demo below:

```css
.mycontainer {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: max-content; /* note this usage */
}
.myrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #e7eff5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.mycell {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 48px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: #f8f9fb;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="myrow">
      <div class="mycell">Row1</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo last</div>
    </div>

    <div class="myrow">
      <div class="mycell">Row1</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo</div><div class="mycell">Hallo last</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx very much for your detailed answer!!